# How to create a table from a query using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a file that will drop and recreate a table from the query.
I keep getting a syntax error. It has been awhile since I worked in mysql and am not seeing the error. Another set of eyes would be great!

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );  

//drop table for updated database
//Create query
$q = "
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbName.tbName;
CREATE TABLE  dbName.tbName (ID int) AS 'SELECT
dbName.tbName.ID
FROM
dbName.tbName
ORDER BY
dbName.tbName.count DESC
LIMIT 8'";
;

//run query
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);


//Displays resutls if query ran correctly
if ($r) { // If it ran OK, display the records.

        // Table header.
        echo '<table align="center" >
        <tr><td align="left"><b>Number 1</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 2</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 3</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 4</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 5</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 6</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Number 7</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 8</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 9</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number 10</b></tr>';

        // Fetch and print all the records:
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<tr><td align="left">' . $row['Number_1'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_2'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_3'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_4'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
                $row['Number_5'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_6'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_7'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_8'] . '</td>
                <td align="left">' . $row['Number_9'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['Number_10'] . '</td></tr>'."\n";
        }

        echo '</table>'; // Close the table.

        mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources.      

} else { // If it did not run OK.

        // Public message:
        echo '<p class="error">Your numbers could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';

        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

} // End of if ($r) IF.

mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
```

The error that I am getting is:

> Your numbers could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE dbName.tbName  (ID int) AS 'SELECTdbName.tbNam' at line 2
>
> Query: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbName.tbName;
>   CREATE TABLE  dbName.tbName (ID int) AS 'SELECT
>   dbName.tbName.ID
>   FROM
>   dbName.tbName
>   ORDER BY
>   dbName.tbName.count DESC
>   LIMIT 8'

Comment: Using the `@` operator to suppress errors is problematic.

Comment: my not use multi_query

Comment: This is a new one for me multi_query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be the single quotes around the inner query when building the table.

```
$q = "
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbName.tbName;
    CREATE TABLE  dbName.tbName (ID int) AS ( SELECT
    dbName.tbName.ID
    FROM
    dbName.tbName
    ORDER BY
    dbName.tbName.count DESC
    LIMIT 8 )";
```

Comment: No, I get the same error if I change them to parens.

Comment: I have been able to get a file with just drop table working and a file with create table only working. It is combining them that I believe is blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

A missing blank space between "SELECT" and "dbName.tbName.ID" ?

Comment: Is this a **question** or **answer**? Consider to use comments for anything else than _answers_

Comment: This is not how I wanted to complete the file but it worked. I just put both queries in the same file, ran the delete then the create. I am interested in seeing how the file would have been written with the multi-query although I understand it can be memory intensive?